# Virtualenv with only Python3

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtualenv

I have two different Ubuntu VMs first 14.04 second 16.04. On the first one when I create virtualenv with pyhton3 for some reason python27 is also gets installed

```
user@ubuntu:~/venv$ virtualenv  --python=python3 --no-site-packages py3-venv
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/user/venv/py3-venv/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/user/venv/py3-venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
user@ubuntu:~/venv$ source py3-venv/bin/activate
(py3-venv) user@ubuntu:~/venv$ python -V
Python 2.7.12
```

Same thing done on the second VM works as intended

```
user@my-box:~/venv$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 py3-venv
Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/user/venv/py3-venv/bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/user/venv/py3-venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
user@my-box:~/venv$ source py3-venv/bin/activate
(py3-venv) user@my-box:~/venv$ which python
/home/user/venv/py3-venv/bin/python
(py3-venv) user@my-box:~/venv$ python -V
Python 3.5.2
```

I need the virtualenv to run python3 even though I type python command. Any ideas how to do it?

[UPDATE]

This is the strangest thing I have ever seen

```
(py3-venv) user@ubuntu:~/venv$ which python
/home/user/venv/py3-venv/bin/python
(py3-venv) user@ubuntu:~/venv$ python -V
Python 2.7.12
(py3-venv) user@ubuntu:~/venv$ ./py3-venv/bin/python -V
Python 3.4.3
```

[UPDATE 2]

I am completely lost... Even `strace python` command points to the correct file

```
(py3-venv) user@ubuntu:~/venv$ strace python
execve("/home/user/venv/py3-venv/bin/python", ["python"], [/* 24 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x204f000
```

[UPDATE 3]

If I remove everything other than `/home/user/venv/py3-venv/bin` from the `PATH` python command fails to execute... Please help!!

```
(py3-venv) user@ubuntu:~$ export PATH=/home/user/venv/py3-venv/bin
(py3-venv) user@ubuntu:~$ echo $PATH
/home/user/venv/py3-venv/bin
(py3-venv) user@ubuntu:~$ python -V
Command 'python2.7' is available in the following places
 * /usr/bin/python2.7
 * /usr/local/bin/python2.7
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
python2.7: command not found
```

Comment: `which python` or `echo $PATH` says what?

Comment: @cricket_007  -  `(py3-venv) user@ubuntu:~/venv$ which python`
`/home/user/venv/py3-venv/bin/python`
`(py3-venv) user@ubuntu:~/venv$ echo $PATH`
`/home/user/venv/py3-venv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

Comment: Looks okay to me... You said you "did the same thing" the second time, but your command is actually different. Specifically, `--python=python3` vs `-p /usr/bin/python3`

Comment: @cricket_007 - snippets were from different attempts but I have tried everything the same as well same result. The most important line to me is the `Already using interpreter /usr/bin/python3` line

Comment: have you aliased the command "python"?

Comment: @Dennis Kuypers I checked `.bashrc` file and there are no aliases for python. Thnks

Comment: @gh0st what is your shell? maybe you are not using something bash-ish?

Comment: @Dennis Kuypers I am running bash shell `(py3-venv) user@ubuntu:~ echo $SHELL`
`/bin/bash`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was wrong with my virtual environment. Apparently, somebody created a `.bash_aliases` file in user's home directory and created alias to use python27 when `python` command was executed and that was overriding my venv's python.

```
(py3-venv) user@ubuntu:~$ python -V
Python 3.4.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the point about the virtual env.  You can do some other things:

**Firstly** I remove the python alias (from the other answer) in .bashrc

**Then** I create a Python 3 virtual environment:

```
$ mkdir venv
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ cd venv
[vagrant@localhost venv]$ virtualenv -p python3 python3_virtualenv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/local/bin/python3
Using base prefix '/usr/local'
New python executable in /home/vagrant/venv/python3_virtualenv /bin/python3
Also creating executable in /home/vagrant/venv/python3_virtualenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
[vagrant@localhost venv]$ source ~/venv/python3_virtualenv/bin/activate
(python3_virtualenv) [vagrant@localhost venv]$
```

**Python 3** has been successfully installed as a virtualenv.

1. You can add the following line to your .bash_profile:

   source ~/venv/python3_virtualenv/bin/activate

I will now log **out**, and then log in **again**:

```
$ vagrant ssh
Last login: Sat Jun  3 00:01:21 2017 from 10.0.2.2
(python3_virtualenv) [vagrant@localhost ~]$ python
Python 3.5.0 (default, Jun  2 2017, 18:10:55)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

The source *~/venv/python3_virtualenv/bin/activate* command has been run automatically, and when I type *python*, Python **3.5.0** is found.

---

**The second option is to create a python symbolic link to python 3:**

2. The second option is to add a python symbolic link in /usr/local/bin.  This will overide the python (in the /usr/bin directory).

I installed Python 3 manually in the /usr/local/bin directory.

Python 2 is in /usr/bin directory:

```
$ vagrant ssh
Last login: Sat Jun  3 00:39:12 2017 from 10.0.2.2

[vagrant@localhost ~]$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

[vagrant@localhost ~]$ which python2
/usr/bin/python2
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ cd /usr/local/bin/
```

**I create** my symbolic link:

```
[vagrant@localhost bin]$ sudo ln -s python3 ./python
```

**I** log out:

```
[vagrant@localhost bin]$ exit
logout
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
```

**I** log in again:

```
rhubarb:scratch milesd$ vagrant ssh
Last login: Sat Jun  3 00:41:11 2017 from 10.0.2.2
```

**The** python in /usr/local/bin is now "picked up in the path first":

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ python
Python 3.5.0 (default, Jun  2 2017, 18:10:55)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
[vagrant@localhost ~]$
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to add an alias in your .bashrc file (alias python='/usr/local/bin/python3.5') or whatever your version of python is.

Append this to your .bashrc file:

```
$ echo "alias python='/usr/local/bin/python3.5'" >> .bashrc
```

You can see I now exit / logout.  When I ssh again, and python --version - the alias takes me to python3:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ exit
logout
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
rhubarb:scratch milesd$ vagrant ssh
Last login: Fri Jun  2 18:15:57 2017 from 10.0.2.2
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ python --version
Python 3.5.0
[vagrant@localhost ~]$
```

Comment: That defeats the purpose of having virtual environments. You want to use the python that is in the virtual env, not the system python

Comment: I agree with Dennis it defeats the purpose of having virtual environments, but nevertheless I tried the proposed solution and it failed as well `(py3-venv) user@ubuntu:~` `cat .barshrc | grep python` `alias python="/usr/bin/python3"` `(py3-venv) user@ubuntu:~ python -V` `Python 2.7.12`

Comment: It does work.  You have a spelling mistake in your.  It's .bashrc - not .barshrc